# Creating array of objects in data mapper pattern

Tags: php, mysql, oop, pdo

EDIT: OUTPUT CODE AT BOTTOM OF QUESTION

I just posted a question, thinking my problem was the query, but it turns out it's my PHP code.

Here's the problem. I have a GoalChallenge class, which has numerous properties, one of which should be one, or an array of ProductService objects; see GoalChallenge class below (note I have stripped out the other getters and setters, and left the ones that relate to the ProductService class.

When I use GoalChallenge::findByPersonaId, a ProductService object is created and relates to the matching GoalChallenge object, but there should be 2 ProductService objects within the GoalChallenge->product_service property (the query should match 2 rows). Instead, a duplicate GoalChallenge object is created, containing the same property values for everything other than the product_service property, which contains the 2nd matching object from the query.

I need the two matching ProductService objects to be part of the same GoalChallenge object (as matched by the query) - how can I make this happen?

If you need anything else, please ask. Really appreciate any help! Code below;

GoalChallenge.class.php

```
<?php

class GoalChallenge
{
    private $id;
    private $persona_id;
    private $title;
    private $item_category;
    private $description;
    private $solution;
    private $product_service;
    private $research_checklist;
    private $subtopics;
    private $keywords;
    private $status;


    public function __construct(
        $id = null, 
        $persona_id = null, 
        $title = null, 
        $item_category = null, 
        $description = null,
        $solution = null,
        ProductService $product_service = null,
        $research_checklist = null,
        $subtopics = null, 
        $keywords = null, 
        $status = null
    ) {
        $this->id = $id;
        $this->persona_id = $persona_id;
        $this->title = $title;
        $this->item_category = $item_category;
        $this->description = $description;
        $this->solution = $solution;
        $this->product_service = $product_service;
        $this->research_checklist = $research_checklist;
        $this->subtopics = $subtopics;
        $this->keywords = $keywords;
        $this->status = $status;
    }

    public function getProductService()
    {
        return $this->product_service;
    }

    public function setProductService(ProductService $product_service)
    {
        $this->product_service = $product_service;
    }

}
```

And my GoalChallengeMapper.class.php;

```
class GoalChallengeMapper
{

    protected $dblayer;

    public function __construct(PDO $dblayer)
    {
        $this->dblayer = $dblayer;
    }

    public function saveField($id, $field, $data)
    {
        try {
            $this->dblayer->beginTransaction();
            $stmt = $this->dblayer->prepare("UPDATE goals_challenges SET $field = :data WHERE id = :id");
            $stmt->bindParam(':id', $id);
            $stmt->bindParam(':data', $data);
            $stmt->execute();

            $this->dblayer->commit();

            return $stmt->rowCount();

        } catch(PDOException $e) {
            $this->dblayer->rollBack();
            echo $e->getMessage();
            exit;
        }

    }

    public function findByPersonaId($persona_id)
    {
        try {
            $this->dblayer->beginTransaction();
            $stmt = $this->dblayer->prepare("SELECT goals_challenges.*, products_services.id as psid, products_services.url, products_services.feature_benefit from goals_challenges LEFT JOIN products_services ON goals_challenges.id = products_services.goal_challenge_id WHERE goals_challenges.persona_id = :persona_id");
            $stmt->bindParam(':persona_id', $persona_id);
            $stmt->execute();

            $this->dblayer->commit();

            $result_set = array();

            while ($row = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {
                $result_set[] = $this->mapObject($row); 
            }

            return $result_set;

        } catch (PDOException $e) {
            $this->dblayer->rollBack();
            echo $e->getMessage();
            exit;
        }
    }

    public function mapObject(array $row)
    {
        $entry = new GoalChallenge();
        $entry->setId($row['id']);
        $entry->setPersonaId($row['persona_id']);
        $entry->setTitle($row['title']);
        $entry->setItemCategory($row['item_category']);
        $entry->setDescription($row['description']);
        $entry->setSolution($row['solution']);
        $entry->setProductService(new ProductService($row['psid'], $row['id'], $row['url'], explode(',', $row['feature_benefit'])));
        $entry->SetResearchChecklist($row['research_checklist']);
        $entry->setSubtopics($row['subtopics']);
        $entry->setKeywords($row['keywords']);
        $entry->setStatus($row['status']);

        return $entry;
    }
}
```

And finally, my ProductService class (minus getters and setters)

```
class ProductService
{
    private $id;
    private $goal_challenge_id;
    private $url;
    private $feature_benefit = [];

    public function __construct($id = null, $goal_challenge_id = null, $url = null, array $feature_benefit = null)
    {   
        $this->id = $id;
        $this->goal_challenge_id = $goal_challenge_id;
        $this->url = $url;
        $this->feature_benefit = $feature_benefit;
    }
}
```

THIS IS THE OUTPUT

```
GoalChallenge Object
(
    [id:GoalChallenge:private] => 173
    [persona_id:GoalChallenge:private] => 14
    [title:GoalChallenge:private] => Lead Gen
    [item_category:GoalChallenge:private] => Business Challenge
    [description:GoalChallenge:private] => 


    [solution:GoalChallenge:private] => Advertising
    [product_service:GoalChallenge:private] => ProductService Object
        (
            [id:ProductService:private] => 1
            [goal_challenge_id:ProductService:private] => 173
            [url:ProductService:private] => www.google.com
            [feature_benefit:ProductService:private] => Array
                (
                    [0] => good for testing
                    [1] =>  mobile
                )

        )

    [research_checklist:GoalChallenge:private] => 0,0,0,0,0,0
    [subtopics:GoalChallenge:private] => 
    [keywords:GoalChallenge:private] => ,,,,
    [status:GoalChallenge:private] => 1
)

GoalChallenge Object
(
    [id:GoalChallenge:private] => 173
    [persona_id:GoalChallenge:private] => 14
    [title:GoalChallenge:private] => Lead Gen
    [item_category:GoalChallenge:private] => Business Challenge
    [description:GoalChallenge:private] => 


    [solution:GoalChallenge:private] => Advertising
    [product_service:GoalChallenge:private] => ProductService Object
        (
            [id:ProductService:private] => 3
            [goal_challenge_id:ProductService:private] => 173
            [url:ProductService:private] => www.test.com
            [feature_benefit:ProductService:private] => Array
                (
                    [0] => good for searching
                    [1] =>  well known
                )

        )

    [research_checklist:GoalChallenge:private] => 0,0,0,0,0,0
    [subtopics:GoalChallenge:private] => 
    [keywords:GoalChallenge:private] => ,,,,
    [status:GoalChallenge:private] => 1
)
```

mysql> SELECT goals_challenges.*, products_services.id as psid, products_services.url, products_services.feature_benefit FROM goals_challenges LEFT JOIN products_services ON goals_challenges.id = products_services.goal_challenge_id WHERE goals_challenges.persona_id = 14;

```
+-----+------------+----------+--------------------+-------------+-------------+-----------------+--------------------+-----------+----------+--------+------+----------------+--------------------------------+
| id  | persona_id | title    | item_category      | description | solution    | product_service | research_checklist | subtopics | keywords | status | psid | url            | feature_benefit                |
+-----+------------+----------+--------------------+-------------+-------------+-----------------+--------------------+-----------+----------+--------+------+----------------+--------------------------------+
| 173 |         14 | Lead Gen | Business Challenge |             | Advertising | NULL            | 0,0,0,0,0,0        | NULL      | ,,,,     |      1 |    1 | www.google.com | good for testing, mobile       |


| 173 |         14 | Lead Gen | Business Challenge |             | Advertising | NULL            | 0,0,0,0,0,0        | NULL      | ,,,,     |      1 |    3 | www.test.com   | good for searching, well known |


+-----+------------+----------+--------------------+-------------+-------------+-----------------+--------------------+-----------+----------+--------+------+----------------+--------------------------------+
```

2 rows in set (0.00 sec)

print_r($goals_challenges)

```
Array
(
    [173] => Array
        (
            [id] => 173
            [persona_id] => 14
            [title] => Lead Gen
            [item_category] => Business Challenge
            [description] => 


            [solution] => Advertising
            [research_checklist] => 0,0,0,0,0,0
            [subtopics] => 
            [keywords] => ,,,,
            [status] => 1
            [psid] => 1
            [url] => www.google.com
            [feature_benefit] => good for testing, mobile
            [product_services] => Array
                (
                    [0] => Array
                        (
                            [0] => 1
                            [1] => www.google.com
                            [2] => good for testing, mobile
                        )

                    [1] => Array
                        (
                            [0] => 3
                            [1] => www.test.com
                            [2] => good for searching, well known
                        )

                )

        )

)
```

Comment: It sounds like the join query is returning many same column values for the related table (as would be expected in a one-to-many relationship).  Please post a sample of output produced by the query, to help us understand what is duplicated. You may need more complicated logic  to sort them out

Comment: Posted output code of foreach loop on front end. As you can see, the 2 objects are identical other than ->product_service, the first object has the first matching row from the query, then a new GoalChallenge class contains the 2nd matching row from the query

Comment: It would actually be more helpful if you pasted the query results as a table from a SQL client rather than dumped from PHP.

Comment: Ok I'm trying to do that now, don't ever use command line for mysql so bear with me, really appreciate the help

Comment: Working on getting the mysql data. The setProductService method is included above - I appreciate this is where I should be creating an array but not sure how to go about it currently

Comment: @MichaelBerkowski I've added the results from the mysql query, thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As suspected, the `JOIN` query's result set requires a little more logic to format the way you want than you have given it.  A SQL result set is always a 2 dimensional structure, even when the data it contains have more complicated relationships (like your one-to-many relationship).

There are a few ways to approach this, and the one I think will be closest to your existing pattern is to change the way you fetch rows a little. Instead of fetching a row then immediately mapping it, build some logic into the fetch loop to create the nested structure your join expresses, wherein `ProductService` is an array of one or more objects. Then you'll be able to modify the `mapObject()` method to handle an array of nested `ProductService` objects.

So instead of mapping as you fetch, create an array onto which the fetched rows are appended. On each iteration, you must check if the common values (those of `GoalChallenge`) have changed. If not, you continue building an array for `ProductService`. If they have changed (like if your query returns more than one different `GoalChallenge`) you start a new outer structure.

$result_set = array();

```
// Temp variable to remember what goals_challenges.id is being grouped
$current_id = null;
while ($row = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {
    // Create a new structure if the id changed
    if($row['id'] !== $current_id) {
       $current_id = $row['id'];
       // Store a new row for goal_challenges, holding all 
       // the common columns in its outer structure
       $goal_challenges[$row['id']] = $row;
       // and it has a sub-array for product services
       $goal_challenges[$row['id']]['product_servies'] = array();
    }
    // Append the product_services columns as an array onto the subarray
    $goal_challenges[$row['id']]['product_services'][] = array('psid'=>$row['psid'], 'url'=>$row['url'], 'feature_benefit'=>$row['feature_benefit']);
}

// Now you can pass each row of the $goal_challenges array
// to mapObject. There should be only one row, but if you 
// use the same pattern for queries that return many rows it
// will work without much modification
$result_set = array();
foreach ($goal_challenges as $gc) {
    $result_set[] = $this->mapObject($gc);
}
// Return the array of results (which probably has only one element)
return $result_set;
```

Okay, that should fix the fetch pattern to do what you need. The other issue is to make the `mapObject()` method handle the inner array of product services. That's easy enough with a loop.

```
public function mapObject(array $row)
{
    $entry = new GoalChallenge();
    $entry->setId($row['id']);
    $entry->setPersonaId($row['persona_id']);
    $entry->setTitle($row['title']);
    $entry->setItemCategory($row['item_category']);
    $entry->setDescription($row['description']);
    $entry->setSolution($row['solution']);
    $entry->SetResearchChecklist($row['research_checklist']);
    $entry->setSubtopics($row['subtopics']);
    $entry->setKeywords($row['keywords']);
    $entry->setStatus($row['status']);

    // Create ProductService objects for each item in the sub-array
    foreach ($row['product_services'] as $ps) {
        $entry->setProductService(new ProductService($ps['psid'], $row['id'], $ps['url'], explode(',', $ps['feature_benefit'])));
    }

    return $entry;
}
```

And finally, make the `setProductService()` method append to an array instead of setting a single property:

```
public function setProductService(ProductService $product_service)
{
    // Append onto an array
    $this->product_service[] = $product_service;
}
```

In the `GoalChallenge::__construct()` parameters, make it accept and default an array instead of a single `ProductService` object, changing to `$product_service = array()`

So this is all sort of complicated, and it speaks to why pre-built [ORM libraries like Doctrine](http://www.doctrine-project.org/) are commonly used. This logic is abstracted away for you in an easily reusable way.  PDO does have a `FETCH_GROUP` methodology, but it is meant to group just one column (like the `id`) as an outer array key and all other columns as sub-arrays. Your situation is such that most columns belong at an outer level, with only those relevant to the joined `ProductService` as an inner sub-array, so that doesn't really work.

Comment: Thank you very much for taking the time to construct that answer, much appreciated. I think it's nearly there, but I am getting Notice: Undefined index: psid in on line 225 (which is the $entry->setProductService() line and the same for both url and feature_benefit too, and being returned in the goalChallenge object is an empty array first, then a ProductService object, but with only the goal_challenge id showing

Comment: Ok will do. Out of interest, how does the $current_id method work - it never changes from null, so how would it ever be equal to $row['id']?

Comment: Not sure what I did. It's there now. Probably won't solve the issue though. Need to see the `print_r($goal_challenges)`.

Comment: Ok I've added the print_r - this is printed in the foreach loop on the front end

Comment: Really sorry - I added that in whilst waiting for somebody to reply - removed now, let me see what I get

Comment: OK I'm now getting the correct structure, but still the unidentified index for all 3 properties of the ProductService objects

Comment: I have tried defining the keys for the subarray, but still getting unidentified index on all 3 properties, though $row['id'] is ok

Comment: Ok have added latest print_r (after removing the group_concat). Thanks again for the help

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/96378/discussion-between-michael-berkowski-and-c-ivemy).